# Multiple Notification.Compact Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, notifications

Morning, I recently ran into a problem of which I have two arraylist (title, description).

How can I loop throughout the arraylist and for each element creating a notification.

I already tried this...
But it always give the same title and description..
Thanks in advance.

```java
int iTotalTodayTodos = 2;
ArrayList<String> strTitlesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> strDescriptionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

strTitlesArrayList.add("Title1");
strTitlesArrayList.add("Title2");
strDescriptionArrayList.add("Desc1");
strDescriptionArrayList.add("Desc2");

for (String title : strTitlesArrayList) {
    for (String description : strDescriptionArrayList) {
        for (int j = 0; j < iTotalTodayTodos; j++) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent();
            intent1.putExtra("title", title);
            intent1.putExtra("description", description);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, j, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "ToRemember_channel");
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setWhen(j).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_calendar_month).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(description).setContentInfo("TODO");
            notificationManager.notify(j, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many loops in the code, which causes invoking the `.notify` method 8 times (4 notifications with id=0 and 4 notifications for id=1).

If you want pair titles and descriptions, you should use single loop:

```java
int iTotalTodayTodos = 2;
ArrayList<String> strTitlesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> strDescriptionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

strTitlesArrayList.add("Title1");
strTitlesArrayList.add("Title2");
strDescriptionArrayList.add("Desc1");
strDescriptionArrayList.add("Desc2");


NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
for (int j = 0; j < iTotalTodayTodos; j++) {
    String description = strDescriptionArrayList.get(j);
    String title = strTitlesArrayList.get(j);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent();
    intent1.putExtra("title", title);
    intent1.putExtra("description", description);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, j, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "ToRemember_channel");
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setWhen(j).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_calendar_month).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(description).setContentInfo("TODO");
    notificationManager.notify(j, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```